# What is this "document.all" line doing?

Tags: javascript, html

*I'm a Flex/Actionscript refugee and trying to make my way with JS/HTML5/CSS3. Some things make immediate sense but then there are others which just don't.*

I am looking at this JSfiddle ["Pure Javascript Draggable"](https://jsfiddle.net/tovic/Xcb8d/) and I am not understanding this line (or rather, I understand what it is doing but not how it is doing it)

```
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
```

I looked up "document.all" and it seems to be shorthand for [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) without arguments?

> Returns a non-live NodeList of all elements descended from the element
>   on which it is invoked that match the specified group of CSS
>   selectors.

- Is that correct? So the "all" param means it is returning everything in the DOM?
- What does a "non-live" NodeList mean? "non-live"?
- And the actual line is... testing if window.event.clientX or e.pageX is non-null?

Basic stuff but confusing.

---

```
var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
    x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
    x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
    selected = elem;
    x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
    y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
    }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
    selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
document.getElementById('draggable-element').onmousedown = function () {
    _drag_init(this);
    return false;
};

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

Comment: No, `document.all` is an old Microsoft IE thing. It's basically a (bad) way to detect that the code is running in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that correct? So the "all" param means it is returning everything in the DOM?

Yes. Every single one of the elements in the page is put inside a 1-D, array-like structure and handed to you.

> What does a "non-live" NodeList mean? "non-live"?

[NodeLists can be live or non-live](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#A_sometimes-live_collection). A live NodeList means the array elements change when the relevant DOM changes (i.e.: If I removed an `<a>` from the DOM, a live NodeList gathering all `<a>`s would magically lose one element). A non-live is well... one that doesn't change. (i.e.: If I removed an `<a>` from the DOM, a non-live NodeList gathering all `<a>`s would still have reference to the removed `<a>`).

> And the actual line is... testing if window.event.clientX or e.pageX is non-null?

`document.all` is probably being used [to check what browser is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10350151/575527). In this case, it checks which event object to use, whether the global event or the local event.

Answer (score 1):

> document.all?

is checking if the method exists (inside ternary assignment)

---

> What does a "non-live" NodeList mean? "non-live"?

means that if you do actions on the items of the retrieved nodeList that would effect the nodeList you're safe that the list won't change;
(the typical example is selecting by classname and then changing the classname);
if you had obtained your list from getElementsByClassName the list would update right away effecting the list.

---

that said in your example script you're never using querySelectorAll(),

quoting pointy's comment

> 'document.all is an old Microsoft IE thing. It's basically a (bad) way to detect that the code is running in Internet Explorer.'